# Opencv with ubuntu-sdk

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, compiling, ubuntu-sdk

I am trying to use OpenCV with ubuntu-sdk for an app.
I am using the qml app with c++ using the cmake template, downloaded the opencv source in the modules folder and added at the backend/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(modules/opencv)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/modules/opencv/lib")
```

It compiles but if i include opencv it throws an error that it cant find the files.

I dont know much for cmake and qt, so any help will be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly found out that it couldnt find some headers because i didnt properly copied them (silly me).

But it didnt solve the linking problem. I managed to solve that with manually compiling opencv for every architecture and inlcuding the library files in the project, following this project as a reference:
https://github.com/nikwen/ubuntu-tox-client